# with php recursion get the city from database

Tags: php, recursion

i have a reccuring function that i want to call it again with the correct syntax how to do it?i have in database if its a country it holds V:  and it has the format Col1 CountryName; col1 if its a city it doesnt have V: if its a region in country it has V: so this recursion has to be until we get the cities that are in one country in the database Country= V:area1, V:area2...Area1=City1 or Another V:area ant that so until we get to city names..here what ive done so far and i am closo but i don't know how to call again the same function

```
   function recur($d,$rek,&$aeroPole1)
  {
if(substr_count( $d, 'V:'))
  {

    $aeroPole=preg_replace('"V:"','',$d); 

    $aeroPole=explode(",",$aeroPole);

    foreach($aeroPole as $ap)
    {
          $mysqliObj3 = new mysqli('localhost','usr','pass', 'trevo');
          $comand6="SELECT * FROM `CC` WHERE name='".$ap."';";  //  name='".$RuleD[0]."';";
          $QueryObj6 = $mysqliObj3->query($comand6, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

          $dArea=$QueryObj6->fetch_assoc();
          $QueryObj6->close();


          if($dArea!="")
          {$rek+=1;
             $aeroPole1=array_merge($aeroPole1,recur((string)$dArea["airport_codes"],$rek,$aeroPole1));

            $fore++;

        }

    }//foreach




}
}
```

edit: closed a bracket

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [link][http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/] - especially the modified tree traversal on page 2 of that tutorial.  Country->Region->City->Airport seems perfect for a tree.  No need for recursion !

Comment: You're opening a new database connection inside the loop? This should not be required, re-use the same database connection, you'll only need one for the whole script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $aeroPole1=array_unique($aeroPole1);
    return $aeroPole1;

else
{
     $aeroPole1=explode(",",$d);


  return $aeroPole1;
}
```

the other case if it hasn't v:

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

After the end of the // `foreach`

```
$aeroPole1=array_unique($aeroPole1);
    return $aeroPole1;
```

the unique is to not have any duplicates, and then you return the function